# Mysql query taking long to run

Tags: mysql

I am running this query.

```
SELECT dom,
COUNT(url) AS counted
FROM results 
GROUP BY dom
ORDER BY COUNT(url) DESC;
```

I have dom indexed but I cant index url because its a longtext. what can I do to make it faster?

Comment: Can you provide the EXPLAIN output for this query?

Comment: You could try to add a column with the hash of the `url`. Something like `url_hash CHAR(40) NOT NULL`, and put an index on that

Comment: @Znarkus how can i do that?
EXPLAINED: 


'1', 'SIMPLE', 'results', 'index', NULL, 'domain_index', '258', NULL, '3684244', 'Using temporary; Using filesort'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count(url) means to count rows that url field is not null. Perhaps you can increase performance creating and index like:

```
create index idx__1 on results  (dom, url (1));
```

And then change your query to:

```
SELECT dom,
COUNT( left(url,1)) AS counted
FROM results 
GROUP BY dom
ORDER BY counted DESC;
```

RDBMS only need index, no need to take data from table, if you only ask for both listed fields.

Comment: what kind of index are you making? i can't index url cause its longtext per mysql site

Comment: @Dev-Ria, like this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bbaa/1/0  please, explain what are you talking about.

Comment: do u mean creating a separate table and then indexing domain and url together? Mysql website http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html says to index text(longtext) i would use a prefix and thats kind of useless.

Comment: No, I say 1) count( url ) == count( left(url, 1 ) ), do you agree this? and 2) you can index longtext, but not all field, only the first n characters. 3) If you do an index with dom and url first character then, perhaps, your query will improve performance. Do you agree 1,2, and 3 point? Have you tested it?

Comment: When doc say: "BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be given", it means that you should inform about how many chars you get in index. I talk to take only one char that is enough for count purposes.

Comment: @Dev-Ria, finally this approach has improve query performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT dom,
COUNT(url) AS counted
FROM results 
GROUP BY dom
ORDER BY counted DESC;
```

Assuming there are few url's to dom's it shouldn't be an issue.  If there are alot of url's per dom, count's will be expensive.

Comment: I'd be surprised (but I'd learn something) if this actually made a difference.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Do you think the optimizer is smart enough to determine count(url) is already being done once and not replicate it in the order by?  Maybe.

Comment: well it didnt make a big different. I have about 4million records. each dom(domain) has about 100k+ urls.

Comment: @Dev-Ria  Then definitely you need some type of index on urls to count() them!  Why can't you declare an index (dom, url) ?

Comment: i could but what would that do exactly?

Comment: danihp is recommending http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bbaa/1/0    but I'm not too sure what it will do. can someone please explain. is it a combination of dom, url? a composite index?

Comment: adding an index, either (url) or (dom, url) will enable quicker counts as it avoids additional lookups in this case